# Android dependency issue with artifactory

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies, artifactory

I'm using artifactory to put my libs and then hook them from gradle as "compile" dependencies using maven. The problem is I've just added version 0.14.0 and am not able to access it now. But I'm able to access 0.13.0 and 0.12.0 and so on. And I'm getting "Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized" error. As you see in the following, they created to the same path and having the same credentials.

[image]

Do you think there might be a delay between maven and artifactory?

Comment: Unauthorized probably means that you need username/password or something similar.

Comment: Sorry, I was using hasProperty instead of getProperty...